# Can I set Vim's 'embedded' ruby path?

Tags: ruby, vim

When I run:

```
:ruby print VERSION
```

in Vim, I get 1.8.7.

I have 1.9.3 installed and I'd like to use that instead. Is there a way to change it?

Would it use the same Gem paths?

I'm not talking about the `!ruby` command. I'm talking about the 'embedded' Ruby that's part of Vim.

Comment: Ruby is neither embedded nor part of Vim. Vim only provides an interface to whatever version of Ruby it was built against.

Comment: You could try this compile flag `--with-ruby-command=ruby1.9.3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but you'll have to recompile Vim. Vim will compile against whatever Ruby is first in your `$PATH` at compile time, so you should just be able to download the source and run:

```
./configure --enable-rubyinterp # + other options you want
make
make install
```

If you're on OS X using Homebrew, you may wish to just `brew install vim` or `brew install macvim --override-system-vim`.

Answer (score 1):

> I have 1.9.3 installed and I'd like to use that instead. Is there a
>   way to change it?

You would have to recompile Vim to change the version. Just Google for something including `vim "--enable-rubyinterp"`.

Beware that you need to recompile all of your native plugins that were compiled with the old ruby version.